# Emploi: mentionné ci-dessus, susmentionné, précité et susdit

Tags: vocabulaire

Je me demande si les phrases **ci-dessous** sont toutes acceptables et en plus équivalentes l'une avec l'autre.

> 1. En raison des avantages **mentionnés ci-dessus**...
> 2. En raison des avantages **susmentionnés**...
> 3. En raison des avantages **précités**...
> 4. En raison de **susdits** avantages...

Il me paraît que l'on préfère généralement la variante : **mentionnés ci-dessus**. Est-ce vrai ?

Comment: Je ne comprend pas la dernière "correction". Susmentionnés, précités et susdits font référence à un contenu déjà présenté, donc équivalentes à **ci-dessus**, pas à **ci-dessous**.

Comment: Ci-dessous, ci-dessus, ça me cause mal à la tête:-)! J'espère que tout est bon maintenant. Je m'excuse pour l’inconvénient.

Comment: +1, among other things, for finding a clever way to work in "ci-dessous"!

Comment: @PapaPoule : Je fais mon mieux:-)! Merci!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le 3. est moins restrictif, je pense. `précité` signifie `cité précédemment` et pas forcément `ci-dessus` au sens visuel du terme. A part ce détail, oui, les termes sont équivalents.

Le 1. est le plus courant et le plus naturel. Les autres sont surtout rencontrés dans des textes juridiques ou administratifs.

*"Il me paraît que l'on préfère généralement la variante : mentionnés ci-dessous"* => ci-dessus, tu veux dire. Avec ci-dessous, bien sûr, ça fonctionne aussi, mais ça ne signifie pas la même chose.

Comment: Merci vivement. Pour la réponse et la correction :-)!

Comment: Je viens de corriger la faute (de frappe:-!). Merci encore !

Comment: Je pense que tu as corrigé dans le mauvais sens : c'est `ci-dessus` qu'il fallait mettre les deux fois

Comment: Oui, évidement. J'espère avoir corrigé correctement cette fois-ci.